# Error Encountered When Attempting to Create Oracle Database Using Docker

Tags: oracle, docker

I am setting up an Oracle Database on a Mac using Docker, with the image `container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest`. I encountered the errors `USER (ospid: 145): terminating the instance due to ORA error 442` and `ORA-1092: opitsk aborting process`. How to address these issues? [Screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n9zY.png)

My actions were as follows:

```bash
docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
docker run -it --name oracle -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=1234 -d container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest
```

I encountered an issue as shown in the image. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Assuming that you're on an arm based Mac machine, currently Oracle just supports ARM on Oracle 19c, see https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/a79b41c71cc845ad67703be5f1f1646d7c737e23/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md?plain=1#L53

Other versions do not work on arm systems even with the Rossetta emulation.

The only available version (for now) is